# Replace character with a particular String in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a program which should replace a alternate characters in the string with a new string. Lets say I have...

String s1 = "JAVAJAVA";
String s2 = "VA";

Output:

**VA**A**VA**A**VA**A**VA**A

Character in the each alternate index of s1 should be replaced with s2. I've tried using StringBulider but I'm not able to proceed further with it. Can someone help me out on this please. thanks

Comment: Just iterate over the string and replace over other character.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and include your attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 s1 = s1.replaceAll(".(.)", s2+"$1");
```

Explanation: Regular Expression `".(.)"` matches every 2 characters. The second char is "remembered" (brackets), so you can re-use it in the replacement part (`$1`):

Comment: Thanks. can you explain me in detail of how this works. i did not understand ".(.)" and $1 expression in the syntax

Comment: It's called 'regular expressions' and is very powerful mechanism for text matching/replacement. Have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/. The dot (`.`) is just a wildcard for "match any character". `F.O` matches `FOO`, `FAO`, `FBO` and so on. `..` matches any sequence of 2 characters. `$1` in the replacement part refers to the first bracketed expression in the search pattern, in our case the second character, represented in our search pattern by the second dot. So we're "copying" the second char from the search pattern to the replacement pattern.

Comment: Ive tried understanding the regular expressions and the part that is troubling me is the $1 and the (.) expressions. when i write ..(.) it means that VAvaVAva will be the output as it is matching two characters in the string. similarly, if i write .(.) it is searching one character and is replacing with va.. like VAaVAaVAaVAa. but im not understanding the purpose of (.) and $1. can you please explain this part

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go other way than REGEX other simple solution can be, though regex one should be preferred one

1) Split String to char array with [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class `toCharArray()` function

2) Replace the new character at alternate position by running loop

3) Convert back array to string with `new String(charArray)`

Answer (score -1):

have you tried string replace function?

here are some examples: http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2011/12/java-string-replace-example-tutorial.html

You can use it like this:

```
String newString = s1.replace("J", s2);
```